# Aligning several divs next to several other divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to align several div containers with several other divs, but am having a problem.

I can't get the red (checkbox-container) divs to align next to the grey (button-container) divs.

Here's what it looks like now (I think the button being cut off at the bottom is just an issue with setting the developer options to view as mobile when I took a screenshot, because it looks alright in codepen).

[image]

And this is how I'm trying to make it look.

[image]

Could anyone help me out? I was thinking that I could have each checkbox as a child element of the button container, and then position it relative to that. The problem with that method is I want to ensure that when the screen is resized, the red checkbox-container divs don't overlap with anything in the green character-container div. So I figured having a separate div would be the best way to keep everything where it needs to be when the screen is resized, unless I'm mistaken?

Here's a codepen with the full code:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/NWjKwxE

And here's the relevant css:

```
.bottom-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 31.8%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0%;
}

.checkbox-grid {
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 7.45vh;
    height: 100%;
}

.checkbox-container {
  background-color: red;
    width: 88%;
    height: 22.5%;
    top: -0.5vh;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;
}

.buttons-grid {
    float: right;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 38.2%;
    right: 0%;
}

.button-container {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 88%;
    height: 90%;
    right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;
}

.buttons-grid button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    height: 7.45vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: -0.5vh;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="menu_bar" , class="menu-bar">
        <div id="logo", class="logo">
        </div>
        <div id="title", class="title">Title</div>
        <div id="menu", class="menu">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="display" , class="display">
        <div id="speech_bubble" , class="speech-bubble">
            <div id="email_container" class="email-container">
                <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                <button id="submit_email_btn" class="buttons">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div id="question_text" class="question-text">Question</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_container" , class="bottom-container">
        <div id="buttons_grid" , class="buttons-grid">
            <div id="button_1_container" , class="button-container">
                <button>Button 1</button>
            </div>
            <div id="button_2_container" , class="button-container">
                <button>Button 2</button>
            </div>
            <div id="button_3_container" , class="button-container">
                <button>Button 3</button>
            </div>
            <div id="button_4_container" , class="button-container">
                <button>Button 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkbox_grid" , class="checkbox-grid">
            <div id="checkbox_1_container" , class="checkbox-container">
            </div>
            <div id="checkbox_2_container" , class="checkbox-container">
            </div>
            <div id="checkbox_3_container" , class="checkbox-container">
            </div>
            <div id="checkbox_4_container" , class="checkbox-container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="character_container" , class="character-container"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I finished that guide and changed my positions to relative.

Comment: I spent quite some time on your solution, but none of them would have been an easy and "good" solution. I'd like to suggest that using absolute and giving width and height to every div or element is not scalable and will become extremely hard to modify and time-consuming and might lead to a deadlock situation where you might have to do a big rewrite of your code. You should also read about "Flex" and/or "Grid" layout css, this will make your life much easier while coding HTML/CSS. Happy learning

Comment: Thanks for trying. I actually just now got it working. I positioned checkbox-grid to the top of the div, then adjusted the bottom margin of each checkbox-container until it was aligned with the buttons, and added a right margin to checkbox-grid.

Comment: Good going, but I'd just like to point out that the image you shared in your solution and the desired image you shared in your question is a bit different in terms of color. Trying the same layout with flex or grid will give you another perspective and help you learn

Comment: Thanks, and you are right about that, but it doesn't matter. The green/blue/purple divs are going to be background, the red is going to be checkboxes, and the grey is going to be buttons. So as long as I have the right spacing between the red and grey divs, that's the only important part. I apologize if I didn't make that clear in my original post. And thank you again for taking the time to try to help, I've been stuck on this for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. I aligned checkbox-grid to the top of bottom-container, then added a margin-bottom to each checkbox-container until the spacing was correct, and added a margin-right to checkbox-grid to add spacing. Looks perfect now.

[image]

```
.bottom-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 31.8%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0%;
}

.checkbox-grid {
    display: absolute;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 7.45vh;
    height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1vh;
}

.checkbox-container {
  background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 22.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.8vh;
}

.buttons-grid {
    float: right;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 38.2%;
    right: 0%;
}

.button-container {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 88%;
    height: 90%;
    right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0.5vh;
}

.buttons-grid button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: grey;
    height: 7.45vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: -0.5vh;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```